# push value to a specific element in array

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to push values into specific elements by creating a multidimensional array:

```
var rate_info = [];
rate_info[0].push($("#title-textarea"+id).val());
rate_info[0].push($("select[name=category"+id+"]").val());
rate_info[0].push($("select[name=subcategory"+id+"]").val());
...
data: {
    "rate_info" : rate_info,
},
...
```

but this breaks my script and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Please explain the part of "breaks my script". What is the error? where does it fail?

Comment: when I try without creating multidimensional array (rate_info.push instead of rate_info[0]) it works. But I want to push the values into rate_info at position [0] since I got mroe values coming after it in the next iteration to go into rate_info[1] 2 3 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need in indexing, just [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to the array:

```
rate_info.push($("#title-textarea"+id).val());
rate_info.push($("select[name=category"+id+"]").val());
rate_info.push($("select[name=subcategory"+id+"]").val());
```

Otherwise you need to create a new array first to be able to push elements to it:

```
var rate_info = [ [] ];
rate_info[0].push($("#title-textarea"+id).val());
```

Comment: The OP mentioned multi dimensional array. I guess OP is using an array of arrays here, and thats why the indexing.

Comment: +1 And if you want to make it multidimensional `rate_info.push(some_array)`

Comment: Okay I go with this solution create arrays each iteration and push into rate_info array. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you're using a multidimensional array you need to make sure that `rate_info[0]` is an array so it's possible to `push` to it, i.e.

```
rate_info[0] = [];
```

Before attempting to do the `push` calls. At the moment you're attempting to `push` to  `undefined`.